# Android VideoView I get randomly a "Can't play this video" error

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I would like to play a video using `VideoView`:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.10:7777/mov_bbb.mp4"));
videoView.start();
```

It works randomly. 20% of the time the video is loaded, and it starts. But 80% of the time, I get this error:

```
Can't play this video
```

This is outputted to the console:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://192.168.1.10:7777/...
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.1.10:7777/mov_bbb.mp4
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
        at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
        at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:83)
        at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:694)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:758)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:155)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1088)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@969a5ef): Cookies: null
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe331a180: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe330f830)
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@abffe09) exists.
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@969a5ef): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@abffe09 Cookies: null
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe331a180: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe330f830)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe331a180: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe330f830)
W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 516238 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I have no idea how to debug this. Is it possible to catch these errors, disable the alert, and just silently retry?

If I open the url in a browser, the video loads and plays perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Uri uri= Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/yourvideopath");

 videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

You can get the path of your video stored in external storage by using this.
Replace "/yourvideopath" with your video path such as /dcim/camera/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: My video is not in the external storage

Comment: oh, so where is it? can you tell from where you want to fetch the video to play in VideoView.?

Comment: ok. So you are using the URL to set the VideoView. so It's better to use setVideoPath method instead of setVideoUri.

Comment: videoView.setVideoPath("http:// 192.168.1.10:7777/mov_bbb.mp4");
videoView.start();